# Ruby / Rails calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rails 3 application and the following problem. I need to calculate a price based on the following:

- Term range from 1 to 365 days (1 year).
- Tariffs in a tables which presented in two sections: for one day and for half a month (15 days)

Example 1:

- Prices: 1 day price = 0.5 and 15 days = 6
- Term : 45 days.
- Price:  To get the price we devide the number of days by 15 (45/15 = 3) and multiply the result by the tariff for 15 days (3*6 = 18). Final price 18.

Example 2:

- Prices: 1 day price = 0.5 and 15 days = 6
- Term : 79 days.
- Price: To get the price we find the half month period in this case is 45 and again we devide that number by 15 (75/15 = 5) and multiply the result by the tariff for 15 days (5*6 = 30). However there are 4 more days to account for, so we multiple them by the price for a day (4*0.5 = 2). The sum of the two results forms the final price (30+2 = 32).

The period is submited through a from and can be anything from 1 day to 365 days, prices per day and 15 days are stored in a database. My question is how to make the calculations in ruby/rails, so the code always calculates the half month and the reminder if any?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Show us what you have already please.

Comment: Agreed, StackOverflow isn't really a "do my work for me" kind of site

Comment: I don't like these kind of questions either, but at least he took the time to elaborate the requirements

Comment: Ok, this is not a "do my homework" site indeed, but i struggled the same problem when i started learning programming by myself. When you're self-taught like me, you lack those really basic tricks that every pro learned the very first days of his school years, and those are so basic that no one will ever mind to tell you. Please have mercy on good-willed noobs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the modulo operator:

```
79 / 15 # dividing integers performs an euclidian division
=> 5

79 % 15 # gives you the rest from an euclidian division. 
=> 4
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try quite a few things but never thought of that.